# mv cdable_vars - where has my .bashrc gone?

Tags: bash, mv, shopt

I thought it would be clever to have an alias to my `dotfiles` repo, where I keep my dotfiles such as `.bashrc`.

Following a [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839346/4556479), I added this to my `.bashrc`:

```bsh
shopt -s cdable_vars
export dotfiles=$HOME/dotfiles/
```

Then I wanted to test, by moving my bashrc to dotfiles with:

```bsh
mv .bashrc dotfiles
```

However, the bashrc never appeared in `$HOME/dotfiles/` - it's also not in my home folder anymore.

Anyone knows where it could be gone?

Comment: If you want to make an "alias for a path", use a variable or a link.

Comment: Assuming that you move `.bashrc` to this directory, next time you login, how will this be sourced? As your `~/.bashrc` will no longer exist?

Comment: Please also see [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) that `cdable_vars`  is relative to the arguments of the `cd` command. Also to `cd` there, I guess the directory must exist.

Comment: Yes, the remainin step would be to symlink bashrc file back from dotfiles. The above problem happend, before I could do this. Nevertheless, many thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

## How to stop it happening again

Use the `-t` or `-T` options of `mv` and `cp`

```
SYNOPSIS
       mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

so for your example

`mv -t dotfiles/ .bashrc`

If your `cp` and `mv` dose not have option `-t`, then you can do
`mv .bashrc dotfiles/`

There is no alternative to `-T`.

Comment: Thank you for this advice - this should help preventing such mistakes in the future. Obvious, there's a learning curve to the `mv` command, despite that it is such a simple command.

Comment: @Alex, you have to export your variable and use mv whatever "$my_variable". This link that you followed is explicity for the `cd` command, not for all commands.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```bsh
cd ~
nano dotfiles
```

I renamed `.bashrc` to dotfiles...

:embarrassing:

Comment: Whenever I `mv` something to a dir, I always append `/`.  `mv .bashrc dotfiles/` will give an error if the directory doesn't exist.  It really helps avoid this kind of mistake.

Comment: @Stewart this in not the case here, OP is trying to export a variable named `dotfiles` so they want to use this exported variable. To export this variable and to reuse it as `"$dotfiles"` is well documented, `cdable_vars` is related to the argument of the `cd` command, see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin

Comment: Thank you for all the hints. It is obvious now what happend and where I went wrong. The further references are helpful!